# Predicted Probabilities Using Multi-level Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic

I am using PROC GLIMMIX to run a multi-level logistic regression model that contains a random intercept. I am outputting the predicted probabilities for each individual in my dataset, and then I am taking the average of these probabilities to get my average predicted probability over the entirety of the data.

My average predicted probability should equal 
$$
\text{p} = exp(\pi)/(1+exp(\pi))\\
$$

However, I am getting slightly different answers. For instance, when I output the predicted probabilities in GLIMMIX I get

$$
p=.0482359
$$

When I output the linear predictor I get 
$$
\pi=-3.1041776
$$

and
$$
exp(-3.1041776)/(1+exp(-3.1041776))=.0429352616\\
$$

I don't know why I am not getting p=.0482359 for the last equation.

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain why you think your first formula is correct?  Where did it come from?

Comment: I'm just using the logit link function, where $$\pi=\beta_0+...\beta_p\\$$

Comment: But what does that have to do with *average* predicted probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

It's Jensen's inequality: the average of the logit is not the logit of the average.

The correct method is to average the individual predicted probabilities since the logit function is noncollapsible.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. So given the two options, it is 'more correct' to have GLIMMIX first transform to probabilities, and then average those probabilities? Instead of averaging the linear predictors, and then taking $$\text{exp}(\pi)/(1+\text{exp}(\pi))\\$$? Why do you think this is the better option?

Comment: @badabing yes, in a mixed model setting, the S shaped curve of risk belongs to each individual, and the population averaged curve does not fit that functional form. It is something very complicated, a convolution of logits, but you need not calculate it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Adam. I was initially doing the opposite of what you said - I'll flip this around.